# Get term slug of current post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I am working on a single post type template where I show a navigation menu with links to all the posts from the same term.

Now I want to use this template for all the different terms so $term_slug needs to hold the term slug of the current post so they can correspond to the other posts.

I have found many times over the internet this code to do the job but it doesn't work for me:

```
$terms = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$term_slug = $term->slug;
```

This article says that this would do the job: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-show-the-current-taxonomy-title-url-and-more-in-wordpress/

What am I doing wrong?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'myposttype',
    'mytaxonomy'    => $term_slug,
    'order'         => 'ASC'
);              

$current_id = get_the_ID();
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) { $the_query->the_post();

        echo '<li><a' . ($current_id == $post->ID ? ' class="current"' : '') . ' href=" ' . get_permalink() . ' ">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>'; 

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your code works on a page where a term is queried (a taxonomy term archive), not a single post.

For a single post, you need to fetch the terms belonging to that post.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'your-taxonomy' );
if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
    // get the first term
    $term = array_shift( $terms );
    echo $term->slug;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't understand exactly what you are doing but it works.

Comment: Amazing solution! I tried to use documentation to get all the terms but no dice. Do you know a way to do  that? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term

Comment: @GuiHarrison In my opinion then you need to leave array_shift() away, and loop through the $term array.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works well if have multiple terms to show.:-

```
echo get_the_term_list( 
    $post->ID, 
    'styles', 
    '<ul class="styles"><li>', 
    ',</li><li>', 
    '</li></ul>' 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop.

```
$slugs = wp_get_post_terms($post_id,'your-taxonomy',['fields'=>'slugs']);
```

`$slugs` will be an array of `your-taxonomy` slugs that are assigned to the post with `$post_id`

Sources:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/